# Plupload filelist elements

Tags: jquery, plupload

I wan to make, put the images name to plupload filelist. But not change value.
I want to make send value to #value

```
(function($) {
    var uploaders = {};

    function _(str) {
        return plupload.translate(str) || str;
    }

    function renderUI(id, target) {
        // Remove all existing non plupload items
        target.contents().each(function(i, node) {
            node = $(node);

            if (!node.is('.plupload')) {
                node.remove();
            }
        });

        target.prepend(
            '<div id="sonuc"></div>' +
            '<div class="plupload_wrapper plupload_scroll">' +
                '<div id="' + id + '_container" class="plupload_container">' +
                    '<div class="plupload">' +
                        //'<div class="plupload_header">' +
                            //'<div class="plupload_header_content">' +
                            //  '<div class="plupload_header_title">' + _('Select files') + '</div>' +
                            //  '<div class="plupload_header_text">' + _('Add files to the upload queue and click the start button.') + '</div>' +
                            //'</div>' +
                        //'</div>' +

                        '<div class="plupload_content">' +
                            '<div class="plupload_filelist_header">' +
                                '<div class="plupload_file_name">' + _('Dosya Adı') + '</div>' +
                                '<div class="plupload_file_action">&nbsp;</div>' +
                                '<div class="plupload_file_status"><span>' + _('Durum') + '</span></div>' +
                                '<div class="plupload_file_size">' + _('Boyut') + '</div>' +
                                '<div class="plupload_clearer">&nbsp;</div>' +
                            '</div>' +

                            '<ul id="' + id + '_filelist" class="plupload_filelist"></ul>' +

                            '<div class="plupload_filelist_footer">' +
                                '<div class="plupload_file_name">' +
                                    '<div class="plupload_buttons">' +
                                        '<a href="#" class="plupload_button plupload_add">' + _('Listeye Ekle') + '</a>' +
                                        '<a href="#" class="plupload_button plupload_start">' + _('Yüklemeyi Başlat') + '</a>' +
                                    '</div>' +
                                    '<span class="plupload_upload_status"></span>' +
                                '</div>' +
                                '<div class="plupload_file_action"></div>' +
                                '<div class="plupload_file_status"><span class="plupload_total_status">0%</span></div>' +
                                '<div class="plupload_file_size"><span class="plupload_total_file_size">0 b</span></div>' +
                                '<div class="plupload_progress">' +
                                    '<div class="plupload_progress_container">' +
                                        '<div class="plupload_progress_bar"></div>' +
                                    '</div>' +
                                '</div>' +
                                '<div class="plupload_clearer">&nbsp;</div>' +
                            '</div>' +
                        '</div>' +
                    '</div>' +
                '</div>' +
                '<input type="hidden" id="' + id + '_count" name="' + id + '_count" value="0" />' +
            '</div>'


        );
    }

    $.fn.pluploadQueue = function(settings) {

        if (settings) {
            this.each(function() {
                var uploader, target, id;

                target = $(this);
                id = target.attr('id');

                if (!id) {
                    id = plupload.guid();
                    target.attr('id', id);
                }

                uploader = new plupload.Uploader($.extend({
                    dragdrop : true,
                    container : id
                }, settings));

                uploaders[id] = uploader;

                function handleStatus(file) {
                    var actionClass;

                    if (file.status == plupload.DONE) {
                        actionClass = 'plupload_done';
                    }

                    if (file.status == plupload.FAILED) {
                        actionClass = 'plupload_failed';
                    }

                    if (file.status == plupload.QUEUED) {
                        actionClass = 'plupload_delete';
                    }

                    if (file.status == plupload.UPLOADING) {
                        actionClass = 'plupload_uploading';
                    }

                    var icon = $('#' + file.id).attr('class', actionClass).find('a').css('display', 'block');
                    if (file.hint) {
                        icon.attr('title', file.hint);  
                    }
                }
                function updateTotalProgress() {
                    $('span.plupload_total_status', target).html(uploader.total.percent + '%');
                    $('div.plupload_progress_bar', target).css('width', uploader.total.percent + '%');
                    $('span.plupload_upload_status', target).text(
                        _('Yüklenen dosya %d/%d').replace(/%d\/%d/, uploader.total.uploaded+'/'+uploader.files.length)
                    );
                }

                function updateList() {
                    var fileList = $('ul.plupload_filelist', target).html(''), inputCount = 0, inputHTML;

                    $.each(uploader.files, function(i, file) {
                        inputHTML = '';

                        if (file.status == plupload.DONE) {
                            if (file.target_name) {
                                inputHTML += '<input type="hidden" name="' + id + '_' + inputCount + '_tmpname" value="' + plupload.xmlEncode(file.target_name) + '" />';
                            }

                            inputHTML += '<input type="hidden" name="' + id + '_' + inputCount + '_name" value="' + plupload.xmlEncode(file.name) + '" />';
                            inputHTML += '<input type="hidden" name="' + id + '_' + inputCount + '_status" value="' + (file.status == plupload.DONE ? 'done' : 'failed') + '" />';

                            inputCount++;

                            $('#' + id + '_count').val(inputCount);
                        }

                        fileList.append(
                            '<li id="' + file.id + '">' +
                                '<div class="plupload_file_name"><span id="value"></span></div>' +
                                '<div class="plupload_file_action"><a href="#"></a></div>' +
                                '<div class="plupload_file_status">' + file.percent + '%</div>' +
                                '<div class="plupload_file_size">' + plupload.formatSize(file.size) + '</div>' +
                                '<div class="plupload_clearer">&nbsp;</div>' +
                                inputHTML +
                            '</li>'
                        );

                        handleStatus(file);

                        $('#' + file.id + '.plupload_delete a').click(function(e) {
                            $('#' + file.id).remove();
                            uploader.removeFile(file);

                            e.preventDefault();
                        });
                    });

                    $('span.plupload_total_file_size', target).html(plupload.formatSize(uploader.total.size));

                    if (uploader.total.queued === 0) {
                        $('span.plupload_add_text', target).text(_('Add files.'));
                    } else {
                        $('span.plupload_add_text', target).text(uploader.total.queued + ' files queued.');
                    }

                    $('a.plupload_start', target).toggleClass('plupload_disabled', uploader.files.length == (uploader.total.uploaded + uploader.total.failed));

                    // Scroll to end of file list
                    fileList[0].scrollTop = fileList[0].scrollHeight;

                    updateTotalProgress();

                    // Re-add drag message if there is no files
                    if (!uploader.files.length && uploader.features.dragdrop && uploader.settings.dragdrop) {
                        $('#' + id + '_filelist').append('<li class="plupload_droptext">' + _("Drag files here.") + '</li>');
                    }
                }

                uploader.bind("UploadFile", function(up, file) {
                    $('#' + file.id).addClass('plupload_current_file');

                });

                uploader.bind('Init', function(up, res) {
                    renderUI(id, target);

                    // Enable rename support
                    if (!settings.unique_names && settings.rename) {
                        $('#' + id + '_filelist div.plupload_file_name span', target).live('click', function(e) {
                            var targetSpan = $(e.target), file, parts, name, ext = "";

                            // Get file name and split out name and extension
                            file = up.getFile(targetSpan.parents('li')[0].id);
                            name = file.name;
                            parts = /^(.+)(\.[^.]+)$/.exec(name);
                            if (parts) {
                                name = parts[1];
                                ext = parts[2];
                            }

                            // Display input element
                            targetSpan.hide().after('<input type="text" />');
                            targetSpan.next().val(name).focus().blur(function() {
                                targetSpan.show().next().remove();
                            }).keydown(function(e) {
                                var targetInput = $(this);

                                if (e.keyCode == 13) {
                                    e.preventDefault();

                                    // Rename file and glue extension back on
                                    file.name = targetInput.val() + ext;
                                    targetSpan.text(file.name);
                                    targetInput.blur();
                                }
                            });
                        });
                    }

                    $('a.plupload_add', target).attr('id', id + '_browse');

                    up.settings.browse_button = id + '_browse';

                    // Enable drag/drop
                    if (up.features.dragdrop && up.settings.dragdrop) {
                        up.settings.drop_element = id + '_filelist';
                        $('#' + id + '_filelist').append('<li class="plupload_droptext">' + _("Drag files here.") + '</li>');
                    }

                    //$('#' + id + '_container').attr('title', 'Using runtime: ' + res.runtime);

                    $('a.plupload_start', target).click(function(e) {
                        if (!$(this).hasClass('plupload_disabled')) {
                            uploader.start();
                        }

                        e.preventDefault();
                    });

                    $('a.plupload_stop', target).click(function(e) {
                        e.preventDefault();
                        uploader.stop();
                    });

                    $('a.plupload_start', target).addClass('plupload_disabled');
                });

                uploader.init();

                uploader.bind("Error", function(up, err) {
                    var file = err.file, message;

                    if (file) {
                        message = err.message;

                        if (err.details) {
                            message += " (" + err.details + ")";
                        }

                        if (err.code == plupload.FILE_SIZE_ERROR) {
                            alert(_("Error: File to large: ") + file.name);
                        }

                        if (err.code == plupload.FILE_EXTENSION_ERROR) {
                            alert(_("Error: Invalid file extension: ") + file.name);
                        }

                        file.hint = message;
                        $('#' + file.id).attr('class', 'plupload_failed').find('a').css('display', 'block').attr('title', message);
                    }
                });

                uploader.bind('StateChanged', function() {
                    if (uploader.state === plupload.STARTED) {
                        $('li.plupload_delete a,div.plupload_buttons', target).hide();
                        $('span.plupload_upload_status,div.plupload_progress,a.plupload_stop', target).css('display', 'block');
                        $('span.plupload_upload_status', target).text('Uploaded ' + uploader.total.uploaded + '/' + uploader.files.length + ' files');

                        if (settings.multiple_queues) {
                            $('span.plupload_total_status,span.plupload_total_file_size', target).show();
                        }
                    } else {
                        updateList();
                        $('a.plupload_stop,div.plupload_progress', target).hide();
                        $('a.plupload_delete', target).css('display', 'block');
                    }
                });

                uploader.bind('QueueChanged', updateList);
```

// I want to make send value to $('#value')

```
                uploader.bind('FileUploaded', function(up, file, response) {
                    handleStatus(file);
                    var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(response.response); 
                    $('#value').text(obj.file);

                });

                uploader.bind("UploadProgress", function(up, file) {
                    // Set file specific progress
                    $('#' + file.id + ' div.plupload_file_status', target).html(file.percent + '%');

                    handleStatus(file);
                    updateTotalProgress();

                    if (settings.multiple_queues && uploader.total.uploaded + uploader.total.failed == uploader.files.length) {
                        $(".plupload_buttons,.plupload_upload_status", target).css("display", "inline");
                        $(".plupload_start", target).addClass("plupload_disabled");
                        $('span.plupload_total_status,span.plupload_total_file_size', target).hide();
                    }


                });

                // Call setup function
                if (settings.setup) {
                    settings.setup(uploader);
                }
            });

            return this;
        } else {
            // Get uploader instance for specified element
            return uploaders[$(this[0]).attr('id')];
        }
    };

})(jQuery);
```

How can I make this?

Thanks for answers.

Answer (score 7):

If I understand correctly, you want to show a predefined list in plupload file queue list but do not want to upload them. I need somethig like this in one of my project and find a work around like below;

```
$("#uploaddiv").plupload(
    // Do default configuration stuff
    preinit: {
       Init: function(up) {
           // create a new file array for plupload queue
           var files = new Array();

           // create a new file object
           var f = new plupload.File("Test0.png", "read_image_name.png", 0);
           f.status = plupload.DONE;
           f.percent = 100;
           files.push(f);

           // append files to our array
           up.files = files;

           // create a new QueueProgress and configure
           var queueprogress = new plupload.QueueProgress();
           queueprogress.size = 1;
           queueprogress.uploaded = 1;
           queueprogress.percent= 100;

           // set uploader queue process and reload ui
           up.total = queueprogress;
           up.trigger("QueueChanged");
       }
    }
);
```

Comment: Thank you - especially for the example of programatically adding a new plupload.File to the file queue.

Comment: Using plupload 1.5.5, I had to make two changes for this code to work: 1) wrap `up.trigger("QueueChanged")` in a `setTimeout` with a delay of 0 to allow the queue some time to render on both IE and Chome and 2) use the original `up.files` and `up.total` objects instead of replacing them with new objects to allow the queued files to register. Hope it saves someone some trouble.

Answer (score 0):

In 2.1.9 ver, when 'FileAdded' trigger, then files appear.

Comment: Hi, do add a bit of explanation along with the code as it helps to understand your code. Code only answers are frowned upon.

Comment: They didn't mean that you have to remove the code, just add some commentary!